# How do I make sure that a decimal value is passed with a "." separator when I consume an API in asp.net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, locale, asp.net-core-2.0

I made an API that looks like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/products")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody]ProductDTO productDTO) {
        Product newProduct = await _productsService.Add(productDTO);
        return Ok(Mapper.Map<ProductDTO>(newProduct));
    }
```

The ProductDTO has a Price property and has a decimal type.

I want to make sure that if a move my application to another server with a different locale, it will still accept a "." as separator. For instance, if I move it to a server that has a locale in Italy, I want to make sure that the separator won't change to ",".

Does setting the culture info in the Startup.Configure solve my problem?

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");

cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

I tried to change the locale of the computer that I'm currently using for development, and it works. But I want to know if someone had problems when he/she deployed the application to another server.

Comment: "Does setting the culture info in the Startup.Configure solve my problem?" Well, try it and see...

Comment: Question updated. Obviously I tried it, I forgot to mention it in the quesiton. My bad

Comment: So if it works, then you have already answered your question.

Comment: Wouldnt it suffice to set a numberformat inside the Mapper or use a invariantculture there? - jsut curios- . Forcing the TreadCurrentCulture to en-US makes deploying wordlide kindof difficult?#

Comment: @DavidG Well, beside myself, I wanted someone to support my answer. Are you?

Comment: Your API gets a decimal. So it's up to the consumer to provide a correct decimal value. You haven't care about a seperator for decimals because you're getting a decimal and not a string.